# Strange loop behaviour with getline function

Tags: c++, getline

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
using namespace std;    
int main()
{
   int N; //number of bank accounts
   cin >> N;
   int n = 0;
   multiset<string> bank_accounts;
   string account;
   while (n < N)
   {
     getline(cin, account);
     bank_accounts.insert(account);
     n++;
   }        
}
```

When I input `N = 1` , the loop doesn't take any input and the program exits but when instead of `getline(cin, account)` I use `cin >> account` it works . I have inputs which have spaces so I need to use `getline()` only but I can't understand this strange behaviour .

Comment: I can't believe "N == 1" is the problem.  I'm guessing you'll see the *same* problem with *any* value of "N".  SUGGESTION: step through the code under your debugger.  Q: What platform/compiler/IDE are you using?  Which debugger is most convenient for you to try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `cin >> N` left a new line character (that you typed) in the buffer, which you immediately consumed when your first called `getline()`.

You can ignore this character by doing `cin.ignore();` before your first `getline`.

Comment: +1 Sometimes there are many misleading with `cin` and `getline` when using them together and catching the problem is not too easy. Good catch.